# Can a file uploaded by a user to Survey123 be accessed directly from the XLSForm's Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4, survey, surveyjs

I'm working on a **Survey123** form to which users need to upload a csv or excel file. I want to perform a validation of the file content immediately the user uploads it and before the user sends it. For this I am trying to use **javascript** code in the **XLSForm** and **Webpack** to be able to use additional functions and libraries. However when trying to access the file I can only get its name and not its content. It occurred to me to access the temporary file that is generated in the system when the user uploads his file, using libraries such as fs or Papa.parse, but these libraries, not being the original ones but a translated and reduced variation for Webpack, do not count with the necessary functions to access the file.

It should be noted that survey (or webpack) **does not allow** me to use **asynchronous functions or promise requests**.

Is there a way to access the content of the files to be able to execute the validations before submitting the form?